# Proving $-1$ is the infimum of $E=\{\frac{2}{n}+(-1)^n\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

> Prove: $\inf\{E\}=-1$ for  $E=\{\frac{2}{n}+(-1)^n\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$

Let assume the contrary , there is $x\in E$ such that $\frac{2}{n}+(-1)^n\leq-1$.

Because we are looking at negative numbers we can look only at odd $n\in \mathbb{N}$ that is $\frac{2}{n}-1\leq-1\Rightarrow \frac{2}{n}\leq0$

But for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ $\frac{2}{n}>0$, therefore $\inf\{E\}=-1$

Is the proof vaild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As it stands, what's written in the proof is correct (although worded in a somewhat confusing manner), but it doesn't actually prove the claim. All you prove is that $-1$ is a lower bound of $E$, but that doesn't imply that $-1$ is actually the infimum. After all: What you've written works perfectly well if you replace $-1$ with $-2$. You need to also show that there is no lower bound of $E$ larger than $-1$.

---

To rewrite it, here are some suggestions:

- State clearly that you're proving that $-1$ is a lower bound. This doesn't need to be done by contradiction - just do it directly.
- Now you need to prove that $-1$ is the *greatest* lower bound. To this end, take a number $x > -1$. Find an odd value of $n$ so that
  $$-1 < -1 + \frac 2 n < x$$
  which can be done by algebra. Then explain how this shows the claim.

Comment: I need to prove the following: 1.$\forall n\in \mathbb{N} -1\leq \frac{2}{n}+(-1)^n$
 2. $\forall n\in \mathbb{N} -1\leq -1+\frac{2}{n}<x$

The first can be easily proved by looking at odd and even values of $n\in mathbb{N}$ but with 2. I get to $0\leq \frac{2}{n}\leq x+1$ which it true for even n values but not for odd n values, namely 1

Answer (score 1):

"Let assume the contrary , there is $x\in E$ such that $\frac{2}{n}+(-1)^n\leq-1$."

That is incorrect.  The fact that some member of $E$ is $\le-1$ does not in any way contradict the statement that $-1$ is the infimum of $E$.  What you need to show is that every member of $E$ is $\ge-1$ and there is no number $A>-1$ such that every member of $E$ is $\ge A$.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm so I tried my hand at this since it'd be good review.

To show that -1 is inf E, we need to show that:

$\forall u\in U$(where u is the group of all the lower bounds of E) $\forall e\in E$ this occurs:

$$u\lt -1 \lt e$$

Let's prove by contradiction. Assume $inf(E) \ne -1$. Then there must exist a n that the following holds true for odd numbers and even numbers:

$$\frac{2}{n}+(-1)^n \lt -1$$

**Let's try for odd numbers:**

$$\frac{2}{n}-1\lt-1 \rightarrow \frac{2}{n}\lt0$$

This is a contradiction, no n will make this inequality true.

**Let's try for even numbers:**

$$\frac{2}{n}+1\lt-1 \rightarrow \frac{2}{n}\lt-2$$

This won't hold true either. $n\gt0$ and $2\gt0$. Therefore we proved that $\forall e \in E $

$$-1\lt e$$

Now we need to show that $u \le n$. Since we assumed $infE\ne-1$, then we can use the lower bound property which states that if a group is lower bounded and non-empty that it has an infimum, which we can define as inf(e)=a. Now I think you can show Think you can take over from here?

Comment: There are a number of issues with this answer. The first inequality should have $\le$ everywhere you wrote $<$. It's also not the same as saying that $\inf E \ne -1$, since what you actually wrote is the definition of $\inf E \le -1$. I think when you write $u \le n$ you mean $u \le -1$. The fact that $\inf E \ne -1$ is *not* what's being used to get a lower bound and show that the infimum exists; the fact that $-1 + 2/n \ge -1$ is. The last part, namely showing that the infimum is actually $-1$, is exactly what is missing from the original question.